# can someone please tell me why my hover and focus is not working

Tags: html, css, hover, web-frontend

I was trying to set my text-decoration to none but I don't know why my hover is not working

I am using sublime text 4
the color scheme is monokai

my HTML screenshot : [Html screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYwsJ.png)

My css screenshot : [css schreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPNIQ.png)

Comment: i dont see anything wrong with the css code, can you post the html as well?

Comment: I just attached both CSS and HTML screenshot now you  can see them

Answer (score 1):

First of all your given information is too less.
Maybe there's a problem with your HTML because CSS looks fine.
BTW try appending `'!important'` at the end. Like this:

```
text-decoration:none !important;
```

Comment: i just attached HTML and CSS screenshot